# png file can't be uploaded sonata-media-bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I have set upped [sonatamediabundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/index.html)

I can upload jpg file correctly though,when I try to upload the png file.

it shows error.

```
An error has occurred during the creation of item "n/a".
```

my config.yml is like this.
I think I set the png file config correctly.
Is there any other check point for uploading png??

```
sonata_media:
    # if you don't use default namespace configuration
    #class:
    #    media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
    #    gallery: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
    #    gallery_has_media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
    default_context: default
    db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr
    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file

            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

    cdn:
        server:
            path: /myapp/web/uploads/media # Its not good I need to change depending on server...

    filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
            create:     false
    providers:
        image:
            service:    sonata.media.provider.image
            resizer:    sonata.media.resizer.simple # sonata.media.resizer.square
            filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.local
            cdn:        sonata.media.cdn.server
            generator:  sonata.media.generator.default
            thumbnail:  sonata.media.thumbnail.format
            allowed_extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']
            allowed_mime_types: ['image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png']
```

Comment: Provide logs for above error from app/logs directory

Comment: how is your upload function looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check your form: configureFormFields()

The error is catch up there:

```
// show an error message if the form failed validation
        if (!$isFormValid) {
            if (!$this->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_error', $this->admin->trans('flash_create_error', array('%name%' => $this->admin->toString($object)), 'SonataAdminBundle'));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue, but with JPG. For me it turned out that the *gd* extension for PHP wasn't configured with JPEG support.

If you want to see which image formats your gd extension supports, check the output of **gd_info()**;

I am using docker, so in the Dockerfile I had to:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev
```

`RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd=shared \
     --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

`RUN docker-php-ext-install gd`

But in essence, make sure you have the necessary library installed, which is **libjpg-dev** (or **libpng-dev**, depending on what you're having issues with), configure the *gd* extension with the **--with-jpeg-dir** parameter, pointing to the folder where the libraries are installed (the default is the one in the docker command above), and it should work.